# Absolute path in Angular cli project

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

How can I use absolute path in an angular cli generated project?

So I have this path : `src -> app -> shared`
and I would like to write `import {} from 'shared/ffdsdf/my.module.ts'`
instead of `'../shared/ffdsdf/my.module.ts'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a TypeScript feature that allows this.

You can modify your `src/tsconfig.json` file to enable this, under `compilerOptions`, add the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*",
        "app/*",
        "../node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

You can obviously change the pattern key and values as needed. You add or remove folders, you can change the order, etc.

You can also choose a prefix instead of just `*` (especially if it cases problems), you can use something like `~/*`, and your imports will then be all `from '~/shared/sample'` etc.

Comment: i have paths like below, can you help me with proper structure that i have to use
    "paths": {
      "~appCore/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "~appCommon/*": [
        "app/common/*"
      ]
    },

Comment: What happens with these paths mappings if the project defining them is a library ? How will the client application not break when hitting these unknown paths in the installed library ?

Answer (score 21):

better sample:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@app/core/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "@app/shared/*": [
        "app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "environments/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

use:

```
import { someService } from "@app/core/some.service";
```

instead of:

```
import { someService } from "./../../core/some.service";
```

Comment: Is it possible to set an absolute path, for example `"C:/xxx/app/*"` instead of `"app/*"` ?

Comment: trying to apply this in main.ts doesn't work for me, using 
import { AppModule } from '@app/app.module';
It throws an error "Multiple markers at this line - Cannot find module '@app/app.module'. - 1 changed line"

Comment: main.ts isn't inside app folder

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found is to put this in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "src"
}
```

The component will look like this:

```
import { Thing } from 'app/Thing';
```

For me adding @ and listing every path looks like a waste of time. This way every project will work the same.

TIP: Restart IDE if getting module not found error, for tsc to restart.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this. Ive been looking for something like the entire thing of going thru each folder and doing "@Shared" etc was so exhausting! His is def the way now you can just do an auto "import" and you no longer need to do worry about the relative paths. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This needs more upvotes! It does exactly what the OP wants and it does it in the easiest configurable way! As of 2024 this still works!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular9, it's important to follow the following steps.

1. Create `baseUrl` and path in `tsconfig.json`

```js
    {
 "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@views/*": ["app/views/*"],
      "@containers/*": ["app/containers/*"]
    }
}
```

Note: Here you can see that I have also added @angular path resolution to `tsconfig.json`. This step will ensure VSCode to show the correct syntax highlighting.

2. Remove `baseUrl` and `path` from `tsconfig.app.json`

Note: Without doing this step, you will get the module not found error when compiling the angular project. (Syntax highlighting was fine even without this).